# Como saber valores de teclas em Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo básico em `Javascript`, sendo que o jogador possui algumas ações, já implementei o `ActionListener`, porém estou com dificuldades em encontrar os valores das teclas para utilizar no `ActionListener`. Estava pegando os valores de cada tecla por tentativa e erro, porém é muito trabalhoso, é possível saber o valor de todas as teclas mais facilmente? Se possível, como?

Comment: Olá, você pode usar esse guia + gerador de códigos para chamar no seu app. https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Uma forma rápida de descobrir o código das teclas seria usando este [site](http://keycode.info/).

Comment: Poderia adicionar seu código que já fez? Ajudaria a entedermos melhor seu problema!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma com puro javascript :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event)
{   console.log(event);
    document.body.innerHTML = "\n<b>keyCode:</b> " + event.keyCode;
});
```

Veja funcionando, [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahzx55e1/).

[Fonte](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: o [**KeyboardEvent.keyCode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) foi depreciado! para código use `event.code`

Answer (score -1):

Existe um plugin para jquery excelente para isto: https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS