# Pegar valor digitado utilizando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Olá! Gostaria de pegar valor digitado na 1ª página e apresenta-lo em uma 2ª pagina html utilizando JavaScript.
Eu só conseguir que o valor aparecesse na mesma página.

```
   <input type="text" id="cidade"  />                  
   <input type="submit" id="resulCity" onclick="capturar()" value="Buscar">

   <p id="valorDigitado"></p>

    <script>
      var capturando = "";
       function capturar(){
           capturando = document.getElementById('cidade').value;
           document.getElementById('valorDigitado').innerHTML = capturando;  
       }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185897/como-saber-valores-de-teclas-em-javascript/185910?r=SearchResults#185910

Comment: Fiona, bem-vind ao Stack Overflow em Português. Comece aqui para ter uma visão geral do site. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Você precisa de uma página que recebe o formulário da sua página acima e processe. Não dá pra fazer com duas páginas HTML.

Answer (score 4):

```
  var capturando = "";
   function capturar(){
       capturando = document.getElementById('cidade').value;
       document.getElementById('valorDigitado').innerHTML = capturando;  
       localStorage.setItem('valorDigitado', capturando);
   }
```

Na outra pagina

```
var valorDigitado = localStorage.getItem("valorDigitado");
```

Veja mais em [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)